# How to trigger Jenkins job by code change on Perforce automatically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce

I have one job on Jenkins and its source repo is Perforce. Use P4 plugin to configure source repo and want to trigger this job automatically. There is one Polling SCM but still cannot find change on Perforce but actually there are changes. If build this job manually, code changes can be sync and job works well. So why polling cannot find the changes? Do I miss some configuration?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it the other way around.

Define a webhook in Jenkins (e.g. Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin) and configure the git server to call that on changes.

The other way you generate unnecessary traffic.